# How to find the last character in a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse, char

There is a huge array of Strings and i have to loop through the array of strings see which words has a certain length ( `qualifyingLenght` ) and it should be ends with the char `a`  for `Task 3`.

I tried really hard and couldn't figure it out. TIA.

```
package set07110;
/**
 * A String array defined as a static instance variable called data;
 */
public static String[] data = { "Achelous", "Ares", "Clytemnestra", "Eurystheus", "Icarus", "Naiads", "Phlegethon", "Sterope",
        "Acheron", "Argo", "Cocytus", "Euterpe", "Io", "Napaeae", "Phosphor", "Stheno", "Achilles", "Argus", };



public static void main(String[] args) { //Print the only two character name


    System.out.println("Task 1");
    System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int qualifyingLength = scan.nextInt();

    for(String string: data) {

        if(!(qualifyingLength == string.length())) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
        else if (qualifyingLength == string.length()) {
            System.out.println("The words are: " + string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Task 2");
    int count = 0; //Identify the three characters where the name ends with "seus"
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) { {
        if (data[index].contains("seus")) {
            count++;
            boolean seus = data[index].contains("seus");
            System.out.println("The words containing seus: " + data[index]);
        }

    }


    }
    //Print the names with 9 letter that end in "a".
    System.out.println("Task 3");
    System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
    int qualifyingLength1 = scan.nextInt();  // enter a number which indicates how much letter
    // do we want in a word
    for(String string: data) {
        int lastChar = (data.length - 1);
        boolean startsWithA = data.charAt(lastChar) == 'a'; //(have to find the last character in a Array of Strings
        // and see if the word ends with the character "a" --> (doesn't work)
        if(qualifyingLength1 == string.length() ) {
            System.out.println("The words are: " + string);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what about using the `endsWith(..)` method? see the official [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: "The code is huge" - so post a [mcve]. Posting a snippet that doesn't even show what `data` is really doesn't help nearly as much. (You don't need to use a scanner or anything - a simple console app that creates a hard-coded array of strings and then tries to print out the last character from each of them would be fine.) But at the moment `lastChar` is the last index in `data`, not the last character in `string`.

Comment: @zefixlluja oh right, thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet I would keep that in mind thanks

Comment: Rather than just "keeping it in mind" why not edit your question to improve it? Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of good questions and answers - I urge you to improve your question. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I improved my code. Not it is mainly full

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the length before and use simply `endsWith` as

```
for(String string: data) {
    if(qualifyingLength1 == string.length() && string.endsWith("a") )      
       // got your input
    // else {continue;} //optional
}
```

Comment: oh god, thanks. Can't believe that I actually couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Midnight i am glad that i could help :)